# How to Switch Windows Theme Back to Normal

Tags: themes

After downloading macromedia flash, the theme suddently changed for me. Usually the normal Windows 7, it suddently changed to this:

[image]

How can i change it back to normal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Aero Peek has been disabled. To fix it,

1. Check **Windows Experience Index** has been computed.
2. Open **Control Panel** (or just a Start menu or, but it's slower).
3. Type into the Search box:

   > Find and fix problems with transparency and other visual effects
4. Provide with admin credentials, if requested.
   [image: Aero Wizard 1]
5. Follow the wizard.
   [image: Aero Wizard 2]